# ajax request per div

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have 10 divs on my page and each div will render its own ajax request when the page loads. I know i can make max 2 ajax requests and then i have to wait (based on the browser) before the next request gets fired. I was wondering what will be the best way to design such a page.

Should i create ajax request inside the divs so that i can pass the div as a context to the ajax reponse? something like this:

```
<div id="request1">
make an ajax request
</div>

<div id="request2">
make an ajax request
</div>

and so on......
```

is there any chance that result may get mixed up and wrong div will render the result from the different request?

--Edit--

I cannot make a single call as they all make calls to separate service and that service may or may not be available.

Comment: so you want to fire ajax requests in sequence?

Comment: not really. if i can fire all 10 at the same time, that will be heaven. :)

Comment: so whats stopping you from doing that?

Comment: not a lot of code to separate one request into 10 divs if viable at server end, use same div structure on return, or send back in json

Comment: i cannot make 10 requests async and i dont want my results to get mixed up. I am looking for better design suggestions.

Comment: so you want to return a single response in muiltiple divs?

Comment: nope. 10 separate responses in 10 separate divs

Comment: Why can't you make 10 requests async? Your results can't get messed up if you load them into particular divs laid out by your markup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AJAX is Asynchronous, that way, if you call 10 AJAX requests using either `$.get`, `$.post` or `$.ajax`, those requests will fire independently without waiting for the previous ones. So unless you have a special requirements that need to avoid that, just go ahead

Comment: If i am not wrong, my server will not start new thread for each request

Comment: The only reason to avoid this is if you are storing stuff on `$_SESSION` in the server side, and those AJAX requests actually depend on the `$_SESSION` variable, then yes, you should avoid making 10 Async requests. Otherwise, I need more elaboration on "will not start new thread for each request"

Comment: nothing gets saved in the session. But lets say request 1 gets stuck. will that not make request 2,3,4.... to wait until server has finished processing it?

Comment: Not the AJAX request, and I don't think your server either, unless you configure your server to allow only 1 thread at a time (which is unlikely)

Comment: If you want them to fire off in order, you could literally chain them by calling the next ajax call on the previous ajax call's success attribute

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you send only one ajax request when the page loads, and let your server side script return the data needed for the 10 divs in form of json? That would reduce the number of requests sent to the server and the work would be a lot cleaner as well.

Edit : ok since this is no longer and option. You can queue the requests one after another, if   each request you are sending, depends on each other (for eg: you might set a flag in the first request, which again gets check in a later request) you can queue them. I have been using this plugin for quite a while now, and it has come in handy)

You might be able to use in your case so check it out.
http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/

Comment: I upvoted both this and andreas' response because they're both fine. I think this one (despite asynchronous retrieval) is ultimately more efficient due to less HTTP overhead. [update: OK, according to the edit it won't work. But I like the advice in general for future readers, so the upvote stays!]

Comment: i too agree with the answer but it doesnt meet my need otherwise its good to make 1 call against 10.